# Passing a List/model from a View to a controller

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, view, controller

I need to pass a model data from a view to a controller.

My app works like this: 
 1. Search for products and return the list of products in a view.
 2. Now after user on a product in a list I want to pass that model which contains the list of the products back into a different controller for further processing. As well as the name of the product that the user has clicked on.

How can I do this?

ViewModel

```
    public class ProductViewModel
{
    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        products = new List<MorrisonsProduct>();
    }
    public MorrisonsProduct product { get; set; }
    public IList<MorrisonsProduct> products { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
    @model ProjectSeedplanter.Models.ProductViewModel

<div class="container">
    <br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="input-field ">
            @Html.TextBox("query", "")
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light bottom-sheet">Search</button>
    }
    <br />

    @if (Model != null && Model.products.Count > 0)
    {
            <table class="table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Store</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Price per Qty</th>
                </tr>

                @foreach (var product in Model.products)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="@product.img" height="100" width="100" /></td>
                        <td><span>@product.store</span></td>
                        <td><span>@product.brand</span></td>
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink(product.name, "Search", new { prod = product, prodlis = Model.products })</td>
                        <td><span>£@product.price</span></td>
                        <td><span>£@product.pricepQty</span></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
    }
</div>
```

Controllers

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string query)
    {
        List<MorrisonsProduct> product = test.Search(query);
        Models.ProductViewModel model = new Models.ProductViewModel();
        model.products = product;
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Search(ProductViewModel model)
    {
        //work here
        return View("Index", product);
    }
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: I have had a look at similar questions but the solutions dont seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by scrapping this app lol :D