# Passing a DropDown string from a View to a Controller method

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

My question is a two part question.

1)
I am trying to pass a string from my Index view into a method (`UpdateView(string selectProductionLine)`) via an ajax call.  I can get the ajax call to call the method but I am unable to get the string to be anything but null.

2)
After this method (`UpdateView(string selectProductionLine)`) is called, I want it to update the model and then call a partial view with that updated method.  Currently I cannot get it to call that partial view.

I have been looking at several different attempts at this, links below, and have been unable to get this to work.  My JS is not all that great, I am still a beginner, and I am having trouble combining what others have done.

Index View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("productionLine-dropdown")
      .DataTextField("Name")
      .DataValueField("Id")
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
           source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetDropDownList", "Home"); });
      })
      .Events(e =>
      {
           e.Close("OnClose");
      })
)
<div id="Dashboard">
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml", Model)
</div>
```

Java Script:

```
function OnClose() {
    var selectProductionLine = $("#productionLine-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    $("#Dashboard").load('/Home/UpdateView', selectProductionLine);
}

function DropDownValue() {
    var value = $("#productionLine-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    return { selectProductionLine: value };
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult _Home(DisplayViewModel dvm)
{
    return PartialView(dvm);
}

public ActionResult UpdateView(string selectProductionLine)
{
    DisplayViewModel dvm = new DisplayViewModel();
    //Some logic
    return PartialView("~/Home/_Home.cshtml", dvm);
}
```

Questions:

1) Pass a string from the Index into the `UpdateView()` method.

2) Call the `_Home` partial view from the `UpdateView()` with the new ViewModel.

Thanks!

[Updating PartialView mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254749/updating-partialview-mvc-4)

[Refreshing MVC PartialView with new Model on DropDownList Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511098/refreshing-mvc-partialview-with-new-model-on-dropdownlist-change)

[Passing a List/model from a View to a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459255/passing-a-list-model-from-a-view-to-a-controller)

https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there is two issues here.

**Javascript**

First, change your .Load method to simply concatenate the selecProductionLine value to the end of the URL as such.

```
var selectProductionLine = $("#productionLine-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
$("#Dashboard").load("/Home/UpdateView/" + selectProductionLine);
```

**Controller Action**

Second, you will need to change the UpdateView function to take in Id like so.

```
public ActionResult UpdateView(string Id)
{
    DisplayViewModel dvm = new DisplayViewModel();
    ProductionLine pl = _productionLineService.Find(Id);
    dvm.ProdLine = new ProductionLineViewModel
    {
        Id = pl.Id,
        CreatedAt = pl.CreatedAt,
        Name = pl.Name,
        ActiveLine = pl.ActiveLine,
        ComputerName = pl.ComputerName,
        UPE = pl.UPE
   };
   return PartialView("~/Home/_Home.cshtml", dvm);
}
```

This is because the default route in RouteConfig.cs uses {controller}/{action}/{id} as the default routing for any requests.

**RouteConfig**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I edited your response to match what worked for me.  It was extremely close and lead me in the right direction.